# How do a plot a pie chart using Pandas with columns total

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to do a pie chart based on the columns values with the whole sums per console,

So total units % for the whole year for Megadrive, Super Nintendo and NES and ignoring the other two columns using Python.

```
Consoles Units Sold                 
Quarter   Megadrive    Super Nintendo    NES    Total Units   Total Sales
Q1        1230         7649              765    9644          316500
Q2        345          3481              874    4700          274950
Q3        654          2377              1234   4265          337050
Q4        1234         6555              2666   10455         334050
```

But I can only find the way using all columns or by rows.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need `df['Total Units'].plot.pie()` ?

Comment: This will show me total units by quarter, but I need total units for the whole year by console (Megadrive, Super Nintendo, NES)

Comment: So need `dfp['Megadrive', 'Super Nintendo','NES']].sum().plot.pie()` ?